# SQL Server convert local datetime to UTC unix timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am trying to fetch the records from the SQL server between 2 Unix timestamps (milliseconds) by converting the DateTime column LastUpadted to milliseconds.

**Query**:

```sql
select * from Mytable where DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', LastUpadted AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') BETWEEN 1620459590247 AND 1620467586956
```

**Response:**

> Incorrect syntax near 'AT'.

**SQL Server Version**: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and & 2012

It seems the SQL server 2012 & 2014 does not support DATEDIFF_BIG and 'AT TIME ZONE' function.

Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: You are correct. Both [DATEDIFF_BIG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql) and [AT TIMEZONE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql) were added in SQL Server 2016. Are all of the values in `LastUpdated` belonging to the same time zone?

Comment: Side note, don't convert the column in the `WHERE`, convert the parameters. The former is *not* SARGable.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.                                                                                                        Yes, all of the values in LastUpdated belonging to the same time zone UTC+10

Comment: @Larnu,  what do you mean by "don't convert the column in the WHERE". Could you please provide more details to achieve this without applying conversion in the where clause?

Comment: Literally what I say, @MaheshReddy . *Don't convert the column*.  You are performing an operation, `DATEDIFF_BIG` on the column `LastUpadted` in the `WHERE`. Don't. Convert the epoch times to a valid date and time value.